# "This time" and "First time"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the song "I want to Break Free" by Queen Freddie Mercury sings

> I've fallen in love for the first time 
>  
>   and this time I know it's for real

Is this sentence correct, because it confuses me a little bit, that he says "first time" and "this time". "This time" implies that it happened more than one time yet, but "first time" means, that it never happened before.

Is there a way this can be correct?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense because "this time" and "the first time" are one and the same. It's just a different perspective each time. Cf. *The Beatles'* "I'm in love for the first time / And you know it's going to last."

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that he's *thought* he was in love before, but *this* time is actually the *first* time he's fallen in love, because *this* time it's real.